# Why exectuing function doesnt work?

Tags: javascript

I have an input  which when im clicking - i want to see alert with '1,2,3,4...' (each press)

```
<input type='button' value='press' onclick='Clicked();'  />

 <script>
  var t
    function Clicked()
      {
        t=func;
        t();
      }  


     function func()
      {
        var count=0;
         return new  function ()   // <===  new or not new ???
          {
          count++;
          alert(count);
          }
      }
 </script>      

If im adding the 'new' in the return and click , it says : '1,1,1,1,...'
```

If im removing the 'new' it doesnt work...

My goal is to use this to get : '1,2,3,4...'

Can someone explain to me what happens ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the returned function:

```
var t = func()
function Clicked() {
    t();
}  

function func() {
    var count=0;
    return function () {
        count++;
        alert(count);
    }
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/wUF7P/)

Comment: I choose this question since it does not have a closure on the root enviroment. but why did you write 'var t = func()' with the '()' ? you dont want to execute it you just want a reference to the inner func...? no?     I thought it should be like this : 'var t = func;'  and then later to write t()...where is my mistake ?

Comment: You're actually returning a function. The inner function isn't executed with func(), but a reference is created to the returned function.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the count declaration out of the "func" function and into the global namespace. Like this:

```
var count=0;
function func() {
    count++;
    alert(count);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new var count every time the clickevent fires.. You should place the var count = 0 outside the function as a global variable..

oh and btw, throw out the return stuff please this will work properly:

```
var count = 0;
function func()
{
    count++;
    alert(count);
}
```

And call this method like this: func();

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `1,1,1,1` because you are redefining count every time you call `func()`.

In your case you will need to either put the count variable in the global scope:

`var t;
var count = 0;`

or change the way you are doing things a little:

```
var t = 0;
function Clicked(){
    t = func(t);
}  


function func(count){
    count++;
    alert(count)
    return count;
}
```

Personally I like the second one. You have less global variables, one less function declaration, and it is cleaner

Answer (score 1):

```
var t
function Clicked()
{
    t=func;
    t();
    }  

var count=0;
function func()
{

    return new  function ()   // <===  new or not new ???
    {
        count++;
        alert(count);
    }
}
```